# Construction of a diffeomorphism handling varying domain

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, differential-topology

Let $\Omega$ be a strictly convex domain, $\partial\Omega\in C^{2,1}$

We define a foliation $\{\Omega_t\}_{0\leq t\leq 1}\subset\Omega$ as follows.

Let $\Omega_0=B_r(x_0)$, a small ball centered at $x_0$ in $\Omega$ and $\Omega_1=\Omega$. We can have a uniformly concave defining functions $h_1,h_0$ such that $h_1>0$ in $\Omega$ and $h_0>0$ in $\Omega_0$

Define $\Omega_t=\{x|h_t(x)>0\}$, where $h_t=th_1+(1-t)h_0$

Suppose $\Omega_{t_0}$ is a fixed domain, $t_0\in(0,1)$. The question is, how can we construct a $C^{4}$ diffeomorphism $\Phi_t:\Omega_{t_0}\rightarrow\Omega_t$ such that it map every point in $\Omega_t$ back to $\Omega_{t_0}$ and $\Phi_{t_0}$ is the identity map?

Comment: First things first. This seems not to be a foliation at all, but rather an exhaustion of $\Omega$ by expanding subdomains.

Comment: Anyway, how can we find such map?